# How to create a REST-Service in C# without the use of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I try to create a Text-To-Speech service in windows. The API should be exposed using a REST API. Unfortunately I only find examples using ASP.NET. Is it possible to create such a service without the use of ASP. Any hints or examples would be much appreciated.

I searched both google and stackoverflow; but could not find information or examples to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "without ASP.NET"? In which language do you want the server code to be written with? If it's C#, then that's ASP.NET - if not, well, why using C# in the first place?

Comment: @ShayLivyatan Not really, WCF exists and so do many others open source alternatives

Comment: You *can* create a REST service in C# that is **self-hosted**, e.g. contained in for example a .NET executable that you can launch (or a Windows service that runs in the background). It will however still probably be the simplest to use ASP.NET Web API to create this service - but there are non-ASP.NET open source alternatives, if you really want to avoid any ASP.NET bits, for instance [Service Stack](https://docs.servicestack.net/why-servicestack)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto WCF - that's a valid point, but as for other open-source alternatives, I was under the impression OP is trying to write such a service in C# using Visual Studio, but maybe I got the wrong impression.

Comment: You could use Nancy, or ServiceStack, but I wouldn't. Start by explaining why you don't want to use ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the `Networking\Writing an HTTP Server` chapter in brothers' Albahari "C# 7.0 in a Nutshell" book.

It would be something like

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add ("http://localhost:51111/MyApp/"); // Listen on 51111
listener.Start();
```

But it's definetly not the easiest way to do so.
You'll have to write too much low-level code.

Just use web API with ASP.NET Core MVC. You can find more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hi Liam, thank you for your reply. I tried to follow the tutorial you've linked. But somehow I can not get it to work. I created an ApiController class with a method decorated with [HttpGet] - but it is never called. I suspect that I have to configure routing (MapHttpRoute), but can not figure how I can direct all URL's to my method. with kind regards

Comment: @PatrikGfeller Maybe there are really some issues with your route mapping. You can look for example at https://github.com/liamkernighan/simple-webapi or just find some other tutorials on medium.com. There are two valid routes in readme.md after you build the project.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because the question was "without ASP.NET" and your answer concluded with "Just use web API with ASP.NET"

Comment: @Piranha and there is an actual answer, if you look a little bit higher. Might be a surprise, but I'm not forcing anyone at gunpoint to use Asp.Net.